# Load an array of strings from a text file

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to export all domains located in domains.txt file that match exactly with the links from the all-urls.txt file. This is my script:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $badwords = file('domains.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
  $domains = file('all-urls.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
  $newarr = array(); 
  echo '<table>';  
  foreach($badwords as $k=>$v) {
    foreach($domains as $k1=>$v1) {
      if(strpos($v1,$v)!==false) {
        array_push($newarr,$v1);
        $links = array_shift($newarr);
        echo '<tr><td>';
        echo $links;
        echo '</td></tr>';
      }
    }
  }
  echo '</table>';
}
?>
<body>
  <form action="" name="submit">
    <p><label>Ready to submit</label></p>
    <p><input name="submit" type="submit" value ="Go"></p>
  </form>
</body>
```

Instead of `$badwords = file('domains.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

I had

`$badwords = array('domain1.com', 'domain2.com');`

and instead of

`$domains = file('all-urls.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);`

I had

`$domains = array('domain1.com/url/subfoler.html', 'domain1.com/url/subfoler.html','domain2.com/sublink/otherthings.php');`

And right now i am trying to replace the array with file because it's way easier for me to load them like this because i have a large number of domains and url.
The problem is that the script doesn't do anything in this form. Where am i mistaking

Comment: What's with the `array_push` - `array_shift` combination? You add something to your array and take it off inmediately... Also, have you done a `var_dump` of the new variables (loaded from file)? You should show the result of that here.

Comment: @jeroen The script is smth like this: It compares the domains from the `$badwords` variable with the links from `$domains` variable, and after it echo's the links from the `$domains` variable that matches with the domains from `$badwords`. That is the second odd thing, when i do var dump, nothing print's on the scree.

Comment: Yes, if you push something to an empty array and then take it out again, it remains empty... Or are you talking about your files?

Comment: @jeroen I was thinking that the `file` functions is the same thing with `array`.

Comment: It should, if the file is read correctly. Note that it returns `false` if the file could not be read. You really should add a `var_dump` of the relevant variables.

Comment: I did a `var_dump($badwords);` and `var_dump($domains);` and it send me the error `Undefined variable: badwords`, same thing for domains, also it says that is `NULL`

Comment: It seems you are checking at the wrong place. Either way I would use a datebase instead of a file.

Comment: @jeroen I know it's possible with a txt file, database is a bit inconvenient, (need connection, database creation....).

Comment: Sure, but if you cannot provide a `var_dump` of the variable after you try to read the file, this is not going anywhere.

Comment: ok, which variable should that be? I already did for `$badwords` and `$domains`.

Comment: No, you didn't because if you did the result would be `false` or an array.

Comment: Odd thing, I removed `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` the condition for running the script though the form and did again a var dump to the 2 variables and it echos me an array of the strings that are actually in the file. So that means it's readying it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer:

```
<?php
  $domains = file("domains.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
  $urls = file("all-urls.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
  $newarr = array(); 
  $f = fopen("result.txt", w);
  echo "<table>"; 
  foreach($domains as $k=>$v) {
    foreach($urls as $k1=>$v1) {
      if(strpos($v1,$v)!==false) {
        array_push($newarr,$v1);
        $links = array_shift($newarr);
        echo "<tr><td>";
        echo $links;
        echo "</td></tr>";
        fwrite($f, "$links\r\n");
      }
    }
  }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```

I needed to add the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`, because the urls are placed in new lines.

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that you actually have read the file?

```
$badwords = file('domains.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if ( $badwords === false )
     die ("error on file " . 'domains.txt');

$domains = file('all-urls.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if ( $domains === false )
     die ("error on file " . 'all-urls.txt');
...
```

additionally, the expressions

```
 array_push($newarr,$v1);
 $links = array_shift($newarr);
```

are quite the same as

```
 $newarr = array();
 $links = $v1;
```

and use some cpu cycles with no effect at all ...

Comment: I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"error on file "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in`  line 5 which is `die "error on file " . 'domains.txt';`

Answer (score 0):

The default method to post a form, is `GET`, so if you don't specify a method, `GET` will be used and you will never enter the section where you compare the files as:

```
isset($_POST['submit'])
```

is `false`

You can add a method to the form to solve that:

```
<form action="" name="submit" method="post">
```

Comment: My mistake here, but I can see that the script is working, but it's not showing me the results.